# Python coin-toss

Tags: python, random

i am new to Python, and i can't wrap my head around this. I have following function defined:

```
def FlipCoins(num_flips):
    heads_rounds_won = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        heads = 0
        tails = 0
        for j in range(num_flips):
            dice = random.randint(0,1)
            if dice==1: heads += 1
            else: tails += 1
        if heads > tails: heads_rounds_won += 1
    return heads_rounds_won
```

Here is what it should do (but apparently doesn't): flip a coin `num_flip` times, count heads and tails, and see if there are more heads than tails. If yes, increment `head_rounds_won` by 1. Repeat 10000 times.

I would assume that `head_rounds_won` will approximate 5000 (50%). And it does that for odd numbers as input. For example, 3, 5 or 7 will produce about 50%. However, even numbers will produce much lower results, more like 34%. Small numbers especially, with higher even numbers, like for example 800, the difference to 50% is much narrower.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't any input produce about 50% heads/tails?

Comment: With odd numbers either heads > tails or tails > heads, but with even numbers, you have 3 cases: heads > tails, tails > heads & heads == tails. What do you do in the case where heads == tails? I expect this becomes less frequent as the number of flips becomes large. Could this explain your problem?

Comment: @user1245262: (+1). That is a really good idea

Comment: user1245262: yes you are right, i did not account for ties. I still dont get why odd and even numbers as input have so different results. For example using the code from Mitch's answer below, input 100 produces consistently around 8% ties(that can't be right), while with input 99 a tie almost never occurs.

Comment: Andy: You can't get a tie with an odd number..;) but 8% ties is about what you'd expect. Pr[50 heads & 50 Tails] = 100 choose 50 * (0.5)^50 * (0.5)^50 = 0.079589.... (I did this with math.factorial(100)/(math.factorial(50)*math.factorial(50)) * math.pow(2,-100). I expect there's a smoother way to do this with numpy or scipy, but I didn't find it quickly

Comment: User: thanks, makes sense i guess - intuitively i would have thought 8% is way too much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just got a lot of rounds that are tied

```
def FlipCoins(num_flips):
    heads_rounds_won = 0
    tails_rounds_won = 0
    tied_rounds = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        heads = 0
        tails = 0
        for j in range(num_flips):
            dice = random.randint(0,1)
            if dice==1: heads += 1
            else: tails += 1
        if heads > tails: heads_rounds_won += 1
        elif heads < tails: tails_rounds_won+= 1
        else: tied_rounds += 1
    return heads_rounds_won, tails_rounds_won, tied_rounds
```

will return something like

```
>>> FlipCoins(2)
(2506, 2503, 4991)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fun to watch and (eventually) demonstrates that randint(0,1) has a 50/50 probability of choosing 0 or 1. Community wiki since it's informative, but not a direct answer to the question.

```
s = [0, 0]
while True:
    an_int = randint(0, 1)
    s[an_int] += 1
    l = sum(s)
    print 'size: %d - %f%% zeros, %f%% ones' % (l, (100 * s[0]) / float(l), (100 * s[1]) / float(l))
```